# Is it possible to replace fragments created with layout XML?

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-viewpager

I cannot replace fragments this way:

```
A2Fragment a2Fragment = new A2Fragment();
FragmentTransaction transaction = getChildFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
transaction.addToBackStack(null);
transaction.replace(R.id.fragment_mainLayout, a2Fragment).commit();
```

The second fragment is added over the first. I have tried a lot of solutions suggested but always the same happens. I now read that it is impossible to replace a fragment added from layout XML file and that it should be added programmatically so that it can be replaced. Is this true?

I now tried this in the onCreateView and worked.

```
Context context = getActivity();
LinearLayout base = new LinearLayout(context);
base.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);
LinearLayout.LayoutParams params = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);
base.setLayoutParams(params);
TextView text = new TextView(context);
text.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
String title;
text.setText("Pager: ");
text.setTextSize(20 * getResources().getDisplayMetrics().density);
text.setPadding(20, 20, 20, 20);
params = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
text.setLayoutParams(params);
FrameLayout layout = new FrameLayout(getActivity());
layout.setId(fragmentId);
params = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, 0);
params.weight = 1;
layout.setLayoutParams(params);
layout.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        FragmentManager manager = getFragmentManager();
        FragmentTransaction transaction = manager.beginTransaction();
        transaction.replace(fragmentId,new A2Fragment());
        transaction.addToBackStack(null);
        transaction.commit();
    }
});
layout.addView(text);
base.addView(layout);
return base;
```

Comment: Why not just use a FrameLayout to contain your fragments for both fragments? Initialize your Activity to originally show one fragment, then when you want to show the second fragment do as you said above?

Comment: I have tried this and i get the same result. The second one appears over the first.

Comment: You should be doing all fragment transaction within your activity using getSupportFragmentManager() rather than doing the transaction within the Fragment as it appears you are doing above. Unless of course, your goal is to show a fragment FROM the fragment itself

Comment: I have tried this too with the same result.

Comment: Link your code for doing via Activity. It would be two different method calls, calling the first fragment's show method first. I can provide code that should work if you need more help

Comment: in your xml make sure that fragment_main isn't a fragment instead make it a layout then add your fragment when you start the activity

Comment: You are using addToBackStack(), so your second fragment is added on top of the first one. Use a frame layout as Lucas Crawford suggested and remove the addToBackStack() call

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create a fragment in your xml and then replace it programatically.

1. Create XML.  This xml just contains a fragment.  You can use a fragment you created by referencing its fully qualified class name.

   ```
   <RelativeLayout
       xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
       android:layout_width="match_parent"
       android:layout_height="match_parent" >

       <fragment
           android:id="@+id/fragment_container"
           android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
           android:layout_width="match_parent"
           android:layout_height="match_parent"
           android:name="com.yourorg.fragment.EmptyFragment" />

   </RelativeLayout>
   ```
2. Use a fragment transaction to change your fragment.

   ```
   public void swapContentFragment(Fragment fragment) {

       FragmentTransaction transaction = mFragmentManager.beginTransaction();
       transaction.replace(R.id.fragment_container, fragment, "tagname");
       transaction.addToBackStack("tagname");
       transaction.commitAllowingStateLoss();
   }
   ```

Comment: Old thread but anyway. The accepted answer is not correct. The original fragment from xml is not replaced but is visible behind new fragment as stated in the question. Was it really working at the time of the answer?